# Flutter UI challange setting auto height dimensions for Image widget

Tags: flutter, dart

In the `flutter` designed screen I have three widgets inside a `Column` widget. You can assume these widgets:

```dart
Container(height: 100.0),

Stack(
  children: [
      Image.asset(),

      Row(
          children: [
            //...
          ],
      ),
  ]
),

Container(height: 100.0),
```

> The size of the image can be in square or rectangular dimensions.

The content of the image should be displayed in a way that it covers the available space, which I have set as `BoxFit.cover`. However, I'm facing an issue where I can't automatically set the height so that cause an overflow error.

To address this issue, I attempted to use `LayoutBuilder` like this:

```dart
Container(height: 100.0),

Stack(
  children: [
    LayoutBuilder(
      builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
        // The maximum height and width considered for the Image
        double maxHeight = constraints.maxHeight;
        double maxWidth = constraints.maxWidth;
    
        double imageHeight = maxHeight;
    
        return ClipRRect(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
          child: Image.asset(
            'assets/images/photo.jpg',
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
            height: imageHeight, 
            width: maxWidth, 
          ),
        );
      },
    ),
  ]
),

Container(height: 100.0),
```

Unfortunately, it gives an error:

> "RenderImage object was given an infinite size during layout."

now how can achieve to solve this issue and can i set auti height

Comment: you need a structure like this: `Column[Container, Expanded > Image, Container]`

Comment: @pskink i updated the code in question

Comment: Like the annotation , If you are planning to use Stack, you can use `Expanded> Stack[ Positioned.fill >Image`

Comment: `Exoanded`, and not `Stack`

Comment: @pskink are you sure? it should throw an error `Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget.` and if i have another widget inside this `Stack` how can i wrap parent with `Expanded` ?

Comment: "Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget"? why? `Expanded` is a direct child of `Column` ...

Comment: @pskink yes that's right, the main issue is expanding on height of `Image` widget not `Column`

Comment: so does it work or not?

Comment: @pskink it doesn't work

Comment: it throws something? shows nothing?

Comment: @pskink it's throws `Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget.` error

Comment: so you have bugs somewhere else, this does not throw any error: `class Foo extends StatelessWidget {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
body: Column(
children: [
Container(height: 100),
Expanded(
child: Image.asset('assets/foo.png'),
),
Container(height: 100),
],
),
);
}
}`

Comment: @pskink you missed Stack widget. please review my post again

Comment: what do you need `Stack` widget for it it has only one child? just remove it (and the `LayoutBuilder` as well)

Comment: @pskink because it has more widget on that which i designed for an application

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255488/discussion-between-doldurma-and-pskink).

Comment: @pskink i sent simple screen shot from application on chat page of ST

Comment: so use `Stack` as a parent of `Expanded`, something like this: `class Foo extends StatelessWidget {

@override Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
body: Column(
children: [
Container(height: 100),
Expanded(
child: Stack(
fit: StackFit.expand,
children: [
Image.asset('assets/foo.png', fit: BoxFit.cover),
Align(alignment: Alignment.topRight, child: Icon(Icons.alarm, size: 100)),
Align(alignment: Alignment.topLeft, child: Icon(Icons.alarm_add, size: 100)),
],
),
),
Container(height: 100),
],
),
);
}
}`

Comment: @pskink it seems that's solved, please let me check more

Comment: @pskink solved, thanks so much